# Issue with Open Graph tags and Nuxt.js (prod?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, seo, share-open-graph

I integrated OpenGraph tags into my Nuxt.js app, following the instructions from their SEO documentation at https://nuxtjs.org/examples/seo-twitter-og

I'm setting tags from a child component using the `SocialHead` component. The contents of this component are:

```
<template>
  <span v-if="false" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      default: '/images/hero/brain-og.png',
    },
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'og:title',
          name: 'og:title',
          content: this.title.replace(' - M.academy', ''),
        },
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.description,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:description',
          property: 'og:description',
          content: this.description,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:url',
          property: 'og:url',
          content: process.env.baseUrl + this.url,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:type',
          property: 'og:type',
          content: 'website',
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image',
          property: 'og:image',
          content: process.env.baseUrl + this.image,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image:secure_url',
          property: 'og:image:secure_url',
          content: process.env.baseUrl + this.image,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image:alt',
          property: 'og:image:alt',
          content: this.description,
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:title',
          name: 'twitter:title',
          content: this.title.replace(' - M.academy', ''),
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:card',
          name: 'twitter:card',
          content: 'summary_large_image',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:image',
          name: 'twitter:image',
          content: process.env.baseUrl + this.image,
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:description',
          name: 'twitter:description',
          content: this.description,
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:site',
          name: 'twitter:site',
          content: '@mdotacademy',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:creator',
          name: 'twitter:creator',
          content: '@markshust',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I'm using Google Chrome's "Open Graph Preview" extension and locally, they all appear to work and preview correctly:

[image]
[image]

However, when I deploy these updates to production and check again, all of the Open Graph preview tools I use do not seem to find the tags:

[image]
[image]

I have also tested LinkedIn's & Twitter's open graph preview tools at:

- https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/
- https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

I'm a bit stuck, because the tags appear when viewing the page source, and also using a tool like https://www.opengraph.xyz/ -- but not using the actual LinkedIn & Twitter verification tools.

The page I tested out is https://m.academy/courses/build-12-factor-nodejs-app-docker/

Comment: Your project do have `ssr: true` right?

Comment: Also, did you gave it some time? Propagation can maybe be the cause here?

Comment: @kissu I was just going to post this -- no, this is a static site. I'm using "npm run generate" on prod and this site is hosted on Netlify.

Comment: It appears LinkedIn may have been long-caching the assets, as other URLs are now showing correctly. However, I found out that running "curl -v -A Twitterbot https://m.academy/courses/build-12-factor-nodejs-app-docker/" does not return the twitter:card meta tag. I'm trying to diagnose why this is the case, and if hard-coding this tag someplace may fix the issue.

Comment: So, you do have `target: static` and `ssr: false`?

Comment: @kissu tested "yarn generate" locally, and the twitter:cart HTML element *is* showing in the final result. I do have prerender.io enabled on prod, clearing the prod cache and will try disabling this service to make sure it's not doing anything weird.

Comment: Why are you using `prerender.io` if you can already have a static generated content with vanilla Nuxt?

Comment: @kissu Prerender.io was the issue -- I'm not sure, it may have been enabled from when before I had target static a long time ago. Thanks for your speedy replies!

Comment: Still, you probably do have `ssr: true` (default value) otherwise you'll never get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, getting rid of `prerender.io` was enough to fix the SEO issue, since the configuration was properly done.